# Postgres Alter Column Datatype & Update Values

Tags: postgresql

I am new to writing postgres queries, I am stuck at a problem where the price is a string having $ prefix, I want to change the data type of column price to float and update the values by removing the $ prefix. Can someone help me do that?

```
bootcamp=# SELECT * FROM car;
 id |  make   |        model        |   price
----+---------+---------------------+-----------
  1 | Ford    | Explorer Sport Trac | $92075.96
  2 | GMC     | Safari              | $81521.80
  3 | Mercury | Grand Marquis       | $64391.84
(3 rows)

bootcamp=# \d car
                                   Table "public.car"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |             Default
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------
 id     | bigint                |           | not null | nextval('car_id_seq'::regclass)
 make   | character varying(50) |           | not null |
 model  | character varying(50) |           | not null |
 price  | character varying(50) |           | not null |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cleanup the string while altering the table:

```
alter table car
   alter column price type numeric using substr(price, 2)::numeric;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to disable safe update mode to update without `WHERE` clause:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Then remove '$' from all rows:

```
UPDATE car SET price = replace(price, '$', '');
```

Then change the column type:

```
 ALTER TABLE car ALTER COLUMN price TYPE your_desired_type;
```

If you want to enable safe update mode again:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, Danial, for the `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` thing, anyways I got an error while altering the column data type `column "price" cannot be cast automatically to type numeric`, which is resolved by @a_horse_with_no_name